# mongo : not authorizeed on admin to execute on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, rhel

I am new to Mongod, and have to get up a cluster. The db is started with --replSet=Data and I have created the cluster with rs.Initiate beforehand. But this question is about user administration.

This replica set was set up with this command:

```
rs.initiate({ _id : "Data",members: [
{ _id: 0, host: "srv1:27017" },
{ _id: 1, host: "srv2:27017" },
{ _id: 2, host: "srv3:27017" , arbiterOnly: true }
})
```

And the server was started with `$ /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet=rs0`

Note that I have not yet configured the other nodes/added these into the cluster as far as I am aware, but I did distribute the `keyFile: /etc/mongod/keyfile` to each server.

An `rs.status` says it's not running.

```
> rs.Status();
{
"ok : 0"
"errmsg" : no replset config has been received",
"code" : 94,
"codename" : "NotYetInitialized"
}
```

I have run into some nib problems.

I created a user before called mgdb with the command :

```
# mongo admin -port 27017 
> db.createUser ( {  
user : 'mgdb', pwd: 'password', roles: [ { roles: root, db: admin } ]
})
```

This returned ok.

Next I tried with,

```
$ mongo --authenticationDatabase admin --username "mgdb" --password "password"
```

but got an error

```
E QUERY  [js] Error authentication failed.
```

Next I tried to see the user list,

```
> show users;
not authorizeed on admin to execute on admin to execute command { UserInfo: 1.0}, lsid: { id: UID"xxxxxxxx") }. $db: "admin" }  DB.prototy[e.getUsers@.....
```

So, I am bit lost. I used mysql a few years ago, but have not used it since. My dB experience is very little.

Although I can connect as the admin user, the admin user does not seem to have rights to do basic "show users;"

Where can I look in the dB to find out what went wrong?

**Environment:  RHEL 7.6 SELinux Enforcing, MOngdodB 4.2.9**

Comment: On which database did you create the user? i.e. what do you get from `db` command?

Comment: I created the user last week and have been battling since.  I don't recall which dB I ruan this on, but I know I did not type any  ```use db``` command aforehand.

Comment: You should start from scratch paying more attention to what you type. To start with `usermame` isn't an option in mongo db. But `username`.  Still you can try this: `mongo admin  --username <mgdb> --password <password> --host srv1:27017`

Comment: Thank-you for pointing this out. I have corrected the typos in my original post.

Comment: Unlike many other databases you can **connect** to any MongoDB even without password. You will get authentication error only when you run commands.

Comment: You should not mix config file (option `-f | --config`) and other options. Better put all options into the config file or provide all options in command line.

Comment: I did, but the server did not start.   The config file has 

```security: authorization: enabled keyFile: /etc/mongo/keyfile replication: replSetName: Data```

Comment: From your question it is even not clear what you try to deploy. A "Replica Set" or a "Sharded Cluster". You state "*started with `--replSet=Data`*" and a view lines later "*started with `--replSet=rs0`*" You don't tell us on which server you started the mongo shell. You claim "*the server did not start*" however you can run commands. - Sorry, you miss far too much information.

Comment: My tip: Start with deploying a Stand alone MonogDB (incl. authentication). Once you managed it, deploy a Replica Set. Then try a Sharded Cluster. Don't start with the most difficult one. You can do this all on a single machine, you only have to use different ports and different data and log folders.

Comment: I have just a fortnight to deploy into pre-prod and then go live next week with the application. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Well - good luck in this case. For me it took longer to learn it. Deploying a sharded cluster requires some know-how.

Comment: Maybe provide your configuration files - note there must be at least three different files!

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you can create users per database. Usually users are create in database `admin` (I wouldn't know any reason to create them somewhere else):

```
use admin
db.createUser(...
```

or

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser(...
```

When you connect to Mongo then you need to specify the authentication database, i.e. the database where user was created:

```
mongo --usermame=mgdb --password 'password' --authenticationDatabase admin
```

See [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)

In order to deploy a sharded cluster have a look at [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) or [Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just tried again to create the mgdb user,

```> use admin;```

The reply for ```db.CreateUser``` was :

```Error: couldn't add user: not master```

Comment: Do you deploy a Replica set or a sharded cluster? You must connect to primary member or mongos. Od do you try to create a [Shard Local User](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#shard-local-users)

Comment: I don't know. I just copied from a company's install guide:

```rs.initiate({ _id : "Data",members: [```
```{ _id: 0, host: "srv1:27017" },```
```{ _id: 0, host: "srv2:27017" },```
```{ _id: 0, host: "srv3:27017" , arbiterOnly: true }```
```})```

Comment: I have added the rs.initiate part to my initial question.

Comment: `usermame` isn't an option :-). I'd also keep consistency `--usermame=mgdb --password 'password` should be `--username <user> --password <password>`

Comment: Still got the same error,
```Error: couldn't add user: not master```

Comment: You cannot add three members which all have `_id: 0`, the _id's must be different.

Comment: Start from scratch and follow the linked tutorial very carefully. If you like to build sharded cluster authentication have a look at [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/)

Comment: ```_id: 0```  was a typo. The numbers are all 0 1 2. I have corrected the original post.
I have started from scratch several times, now. I posted here after my forth attempt

Comment: have you tried after disabling selinux once?

Comment: check context for logs and data directory

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Comment: I uninstalled the RPM, rm'ed everything under /var/lib/mongo, /etc/mongo, /etc/mongod.conf.  Next I reinstalled the RPMs, and started the service.  Logged in with  ```mongo admin -port 27017``` but even ```show users``` gave a permission error.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA  Good idea. The SElinux pre-requis were met including the compiled modules, and the tags on the datadir, /var/lib/mongo and /var/run/mongo. Otherwise it ought not to start. I'll disable it just to verify there is not something I missed.

Comment: First disable **security** part and keep **replica set** enable.  Then initialize replica set first with **rs.initiate** then enable **auth and keyfile** and check. It worked for me.

Comment: Deleted & reinstalled.  Did not add security to the mongod.conf file.  All I did was run: ```> use user; ```> db.createUser ( {  
user : 'mgdb', pwd: 'password', roles: [ { roles: root, db: admin } ]
}) ```Successfully added user: ...    I then tried to login with ```mongo --authenticationDatabase admin --username "mgdb" --password "password"   and got : Error: Authentication failed.
Also tried with SELinux permissive.

Comment: Why do you use `--authenticationDatabase admin` when you created the user in database `user`?

Comment: no idea. I thought that all users had to be created in user db.  Don't all credentials live there?  The ```db.Create command had the constraint   { role:root, db: admin } doesn't this mean it creates in admin db instead of user db.

Comment: Instead of db user, I did a db.admin, and ran the db.create command.  And can now log in. I don't understand mongod. I wish the third party s/w providor we have had to use mandated mysql or oracle instead, because we have DBAs for those.

Comment: should rs.initiate command be run inside a specific database like the db.create commandabove?

Comment: `rs.initiate` can run from any DB.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but got :

    ```ok : 0```
    ```errmg: this node was not started with eth replSet option```

I used to put replSet in the mongod,conf, but think this is the wrong place.  Is the recommended way to use this on the command with  --replSet=Data

Comment: The systemd service file for RHEL7 is broken. I commented the Environment and OPTIONS type values and instead set the `ExecStart/usr/bin.mongod -f /etc/mongod.cong --replSet=Data`

This started, and rs.status() returned:

`operationTime : Timestamp 0,0`
`ok : 0`; 
`errmsg: no replset config has been received,`
`code : 94,`
`codeName: NotYetInitialized`
`...`

Comment: I already told you: "**You should not mix config file (option `-f | --config`) and other options.**" Config file `/etc/mongod.cong` is most likely a typo - should it be `/etc/mongod.conf`?

Comment: I don't wish to come across as impertinent, but why not?  The guide does not mention the mixing problem: 

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file

Comment: Yep, a typo. `Mongod.conf`

Comment: For example you can set replicaSet name by option `--replSet` or in configuration file `replication.replSetName` - honestly I don't know which one takes precedence in case they are different, I did not find out. That's the reason why I **recommend** not mixing them.

Comment: I tried using `replication.replSetName`  but it ignored it.  Only later did I add the command line option, and then it didn't complain. By the way, can we use `replication.replSetName: Data` in the conf file, or is it `replication: replSetName: Data`

Comment: Got the dB started. 

Not that the cluster is working. Nothing is listening on port 27019/tcp or 27018/tcp. Though it should be.  27017/tcp is listening.

Comment: `rs.printReplicationInfo()` returns `this is a slave, printing slave replication info.` and `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` did nothing.
Whilst the other nodes return `errmsg:  replication not detected` when  `rs.printReplicationInfo()` is run.